# Python3 installed, but why can't I run python file in terminal

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, python-3.6

I am trying to run a python3 file out of the directory the file is located in on macOS catalina.

so I type the following:

```
python3 <file_name>
```

and nothing happens in my terminal, it just starts a new line in the same directory, but no file runs.

Up until now I have only ever used a jupyter notebook to run python, but now I am trying to run VS code and run the file inside of the terminal.

Anyone know how to fix?

Comment: what happens when you only type `python3`? Do you get the REPL prompt? What happens when you use a terminal outside VSC?

Comment: After selecting interpreter, press Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new terminal, then type python3 <file_name>. Try this and see if it works.

Comment: python3 gives a REPL prompt. But python3 <file_name> doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to say I fixed the problem trying a number of different solutions:

1. I downloaded the most recent version of python, ran certificates and update commands.
2. I selected the new python interpreter from VS code using shift+cmd+P and select interpreter option.
3. I ran the file in python launcher and then again in terminal and it works fine now. Thanks for participating in helping me solve this issue.

Alternatively if anyone else has similar problems, try the steps I mentioned, or maybe try setting up a pyenv to run python files in a virtual python environment.